# EntityFramework 4 returning all columns when I just want one back

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I can't figure out why entityframework is returning me all columns on the below two queries. I'm trying to get it to return me just the date column but back all the columns of db.EmailDetails come when I look at the sql generated (posted below)

```
var y = (from data1 in db.EmailDetails
                             join data2 in db.AddressBookEntries on data1.FromAddressBookEntryId equals data2.Id
                             orderby data1.EmailSendFinishTime descending 
                             select data1.EmailSendFinishTime).FirstOrDefault();


var x =
                        db.EmailDetails.Where(a => a.User.Username == username && a.FromAddressBookEntry.WhiteList).
                            Select(a => new
                                            {
                                                a.EmailSendFinishTime
                                            }).
                            OrderByDescending(
                                a => a.EmailSendFinishTime)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

sql generated:

```
            exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Project1].[InValidMailMessage] AS [InValidMailMessage], 
            [Project1].[MailInternalDate] AS [MailInternalDate], 
            [Project1].[MessageUniqueId] AS [MessageUniqueId], 
            [Project1].[FromAddressBookEntryId] AS [FromAddressBookEntryId], 
            [Project1].[ToEmailAddress] AS [ToEmailAddress], 
            [Project1].[EmailFolderId] AS [EmailFolderId], 
            [Project1].[EmailHeaderInfo] AS [EmailHeaderInfo], 
            [Project1].[EmailSendSmtpServer] AS [EmailSendSmtpServer], 
            [Project1].[EmailSendStatus] AS [EmailSendStatus], 
            [Project1].[EmailSendStartTime] AS [EmailSendStartTime], 
            [Project1].[EmailSendFinishTime] AS [EmailSendFinishTime], 
            [Project1].[EmailSendLogMessage] AS [EmailSendLogMessage], 
            [Project1].[Subject] AS [Subject], 
            [Project1].[MimeMessageFull] AS [MimeMessageFull], 
            [Project1].[HighPriority] AS [HighPriority], 
            [Project1].[SentDateTime] AS [SentDateTime], 
            [Project1].[EmailDeleted] AS [EmailDeleted], 
            [Project1].[EmailDeletedDateTime] AS [EmailDeletedDateTime], 
            [Project1].[EmailViewed] AS [EmailViewed], 
            [Project1].[EmailViewedDateTime] AS [EmailViewedDateTime], 
            [Project1].[BodyTextForSend] AS [BodyTextForSend], 
            [Project1].[ReceivedDate] AS [ReceivedDate]
            FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
                          [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId],
                          [Extent1].[InValidMailMessage] AS [InValidMailMessage],
                          [Extent1].[MailInternalDate] AS [MailInternalDate],
                          [Extent1].[MessageUniqueId] AS [MessageUniqueId],
                          [Extent1].[FromAddressBookEntryId] AS [FromAddressBookEntryId],
                          [Extent1].[ToEmailAddress] AS [ToEmailAddress],
                          [Extent1].[EmailFolderId] AS [EmailFolderId],
                          [Extent1].[EmailHeaderInfo] AS [EmailHeaderInfo],
                          [Extent1].[EmailSendSmtpServer] AS [EmailSendSmtpServer],
                          [Extent1].[EmailSendStatus] AS [EmailSendStatus],
                          [Extent1].[EmailSendStartTime] AS [EmailSendStartTime],
                          [Extent1].[EmailSendFinishTime] AS [EmailSendFinishTime],
                          [Extent1].[EmailSendLogMessage] AS [EmailSendLogMessage],
                          [Extent1].[Subject] AS [Subject],
                          [Extent1].[MimeMessageFull] AS [MimeMessageFull],
                          [Extent1].[HighPriority] AS [HighPriority],
                          [Extent1].[SentDateTime] AS [SentDateTime],
                          [Extent1].[EmailDeleted] AS [EmailDeleted],
                          [Extent1].[EmailDeletedDateTime] AS [EmailDeletedDateTime],
                          [Extent1].[EmailViewed] AS [EmailViewed],
                          [Extent1].[EmailViewedDateTime] AS [EmailViewedDateTime],
                          [Extent1].[BodyTextForSend] AS [BodyTextForSend],
                          [Extent1].[ReceivedDate] AS [ReceivedDate]
                   FROM [dbo].[EmailDetails] AS [Extent1]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserId] =
                        [Extent2].[Id]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[AddressBookEntries] AS [Extent3] ON
                        [Extent1].[FromAddressBookEntryId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                   WHERE ([Extent2].[Username] = @p__linq__0) AND
                         ([Extent3].[WhiteList] = 1))  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[EmailSendFinishTime] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)
            ',@p__linq__0=N'ekellner9
```

EmailDetail Definition and AddressBookEntry Definition

```
        public class EmailDetail
        {
            public EmailDetail()
            {
                // keep sqlserver from blowing up with no datetime set
                EmailSendStartTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
                EmailSendFinishTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
            }
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("User")]
            public long UserId { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must have user associted with EmailDetail")]
            public User User { get; set; }


            public long? FromAddressBookEntryId { get; set; }
            public AddressBookEntry FromAddressBookEntry { get; set; }

            public DateTime EmailSendStartTime { get; set; }
            public DateTime EmailSendFinishTime { get; set; }  
        }
        public class AddressBookEntry
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("User")]
            public long UserId { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public User User { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(512)]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, this should not happen (for both queries).

Comment: What type is your `EmailDetails`?

Comment: Hi Ladislav,  I've updated the questions and added the basics of the two tables I'm joining (leaving out columns that I don't think matter to keep the post a little shorter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not getting the same results as you.  Using the following console app:

```
   public class EmailDetail
    {
        public EmailDetail()
        {
            // keep sqlserver from blowing up with no datetime set
            EmailSendStartTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
            EmailSendFinishTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must have user associted with EmailDetail")]
        public User User { get; set; }
        public long? FromAddressBookEntryId { get; set; }
        public AddressBookEntry FromAddressBookEntry { get; set; }
        public DateTime EmailSendStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EmailSendFinishTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressBookEntry
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public User User { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(512)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool WhiteList { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public class CFContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<AddressBookEntry> AddressBookEntries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmailDetail> EmailDetails { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var db = new CFContext();

            var y = (from data1 in db.EmailDetails
                     join data2 in db.AddressBookEntries on data1.FromAddressBookEntryId equals data2.Id
                     orderby data1.EmailSendFinishTime descending
                     select data1.EmailSendFinishTime).FirstOrDefault();

            string username = "1";

            var x = db.EmailDetails.Where(a => a.User.Username == username && a.FromAddressBookEntry.WhiteList).
                                        Select(a => new
                                        {
                                            a.EmailSendFinishTime
                                        }).
                                        OrderByDescending(
                                            a => a.EmailSendFinishTime)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(y);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
```

I got these SQL queries

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[EmailSendFinishTime] AS [EmailSendFinishTime]
FROM [dbo].[EmailDetails] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[FromAddressBookEntryId] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmailSendFinishTime] DESC


SELECT TOP (1) 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[EmailSendFinishTime] AS [EmailSendFinishTime]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EmailSendFinishTime] AS [EmailSendFinishTime], 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM   [dbo].[EmailDetails] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AddressBookEntries] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[FromAddressBookEntryId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[Username] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent3].[WhiteList] = 1)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[EmailSendFinishTime] DESC
```

Is there anything else in your model, or maybe there's something else making the SQL query above?

Comment: Hi Mark, you are getting what I would have expected. Let me try your example in my project and see what happens and come back with the results.  Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Bad news for me.  I tried your code, confirmed that it's using the same version of EF (v4.0.30319) and the code you posted produces the results you mention, yet my code (with identical columns, just some removed) in my larger project with more tables still returns all the extra columns.  Looks like I have a "diff" hunt ahead of me.  I'll post back when I've narrowed it down to hopefully what is causing the issue.  At least it is returning the correct answer best I can tell and since the c# is close to the sqlserver it is not a big problem for me yet.  Thanks again. -Peter